# AngularJS ng-class expression throwing error

Tags: angularjs

I can't make this work, any idea what I'm missing?

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="selected:currentPersonID===person.id">
```

Displaying `currentPersonID` and `person.id` shows the appropriate data, but I get an Angular parse error with that expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="{'selected': currentPersonID === person.id}">
```

The `ngClass`[docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) says:

```
<ANY ng-class="{expression}">
   ...
</ANY>
```

The curly braces are necessary there.

The single quotes are documented in a comment on the same page (I know, should be on the official docs, but...)

Comment: Please expand a little more on why your solution is correct while the op's is not.

Comment: @arne I wish I could explain more, but its really straightforward. The curly braces are on [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass) while the single quote are documented in a comment (yeah, I know) on the same documentation.

Comment: You could have written exactly that in your answer, together with a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngClass` directive accepts a map of class names to boolean values. You 're missing the curly braces:

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-class="{selected : currentPersonID === 
person.id}">
```