# AngularJS ng-class expression throwing syntax error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Walking through a tutorial app for use with the [Ionic platform](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html), which is built on angular 1.2.4, I've hit a confusing error in this Angular markup:

```
    <content has-header="true" scroll="false">
      <list>
        <item ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-click="selectProject(project)" ng-class="{active:activeProject==project}">
          {{project.title}}
        </item>
      </list>
    </content>
```

The error in chrome console is:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'itemClass' is an unexpected token
at column 33 of the expression [{active:activeProject==project} itemClass] 
starting at [itemClass].
```

If you change the ng-class attribute thusly (add a semicolon) :

```
       <item ng-repeat="project in projects" 
        ng-click="selectProject(project)" 
        ng-class="{active:activeProject==project};">
```

then the error goes away.

The ionic forum users are wondering why this is. I've found lots of SO posts on ng-class, and reviewed the docs, but nowhere can I find evidence that the trailing semicolon is a requirement, e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075307/angularjs-ng-class-expression-throwing-error).

My best guess is that Angular is jamming (minifying) the class code together with something else and a semicolon is not being inserted automatically before javascript tries to run it; but the Angular docs say it doesn't use eval(), so it's puzzling how it fails.

Would love to know why this is happening.

Comment: Add a plunker please.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when my directive (`item` in this case) was configured with `replace: true`, and both the directive and the element it was replacing were using the `ng-class` directive. I guess angular was jamming the ng-class properties together in a way that led to a syntax error.

This could have been what was going on here, depending on the definition of the `item` directive.

The fix (workaround) was to set `replace: false`.